# Iteratively select a sequence of columns from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and trying to learn a simple way to do my task:

I have a data frame with 15 columns. Column names are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, ... , `O` with 112 rows.

I Have another vector which contains the sequence of columns to be read in every iteration.
eg:

```
x <- c("D", "E", "G", "H", "A", "B", "F")
```

What i want to do is :

1. for first iteration read first column (i.e. `D`) from the main data frame and then perform my operation only on that column.
2. in second iteration use two columns (`D` and `E`) and perform my operation.
3. in 3rd iteration read only columns `D`, `E`, and `G` and perform my operation
4. etc.

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:27, ncol=9))
names(DF) <- LETTERS[seq_along(DF)]

set.seed(42)
x <- sample(names(DF))

sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
  sum(DF[, x[sequence(i)], drop=FALSE])
})
#[1]  78 147 171 213 246 306 357 363 378
```

Comment: I'd probably put a `,drop=FALSE` in the subsetting call since there is both single and multiple column selection. `sum` doesn't care, but some operations might.